# OpenCart - Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Tags: opencart

guys ! 
I have problem with OpenCart 1.5.6. Тhe problem appeared when installed vqmod.

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/*/admin/language/english/common/login.php:41) in /home/*/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_controller.php on line 28Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/*/admin/language/english/common/login.php:41) in /home/*/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_engine_controller.php on line 29
```

This is the message when i tried to open admin panel.

On 29 line in vq2-system_engine_controller.php
header('Location: ' . str_replace(array('&', "\n", "\r"), array('&', '', ''), $url));

Comment: please give the snap or the code of that login page

Comment: This is the full content of login.php

<?php
// header
$_['heading_title']  = 'Administration';





// Text


$_['text_heading']   = 'Administration';


$_['text_login']     = 'Please enter your login details.';


$_['text_forgotten'] = 'Forgotten Password';





// Entry


$_['entry_username'] = 'Username:';


$_['entry_password'] = 'Password:';




// Button

$_['button_login']   = 'Login';





// Error


$_['error_login']    = 'No match for Username and/or Password.';


$_['error_token']    = 'Invalid token session. Please login again.';


?>

Comment: you have add separate configuration for vqmod, to work in your website. I have also face this kind of problem, i can't solve those,so i always try avoid vqmod.

Answer (score 0):

There must be some whitespaces at the end of the following file. Removing white spaces will surely fix the issue.

admin/language/english/common/login.php